# last: invalid option -- 's'

Tags: centos, options, last

I learned from several posts that we can use the `-s` (since) option to show login events that took place since a specific date. However, it encountered the error **invalid option**.

```
root@VM-0-6-centos ~ $ last -s 2021-03-15 10:00 -t 2021-03-15 11:45
last: invalid option -- 's'
Usage: last [-num | -n num] [-f file] [-t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS] [-R] [-adioxFw] [username..] [tty..]
```

Is the option `-s` in `last` deprecated on CentOS?

I also tried it on macOS. It raised the error **illegal option**.

```
$ last -s 2021-03-15 10:00 -t 2021-03-15 11:45
last: illegal option -- s
usage: last [-#] [-t tty] [-h hostname] [user ...]
```

Comment: Tools have different implementations. Some implementations provide features that others don't.  When it comes to non-standard tools like `last` (non-standard as in not a POSIX utility), then the features that are implemented and the way they are implemented may vary wildly. It's therefore difficult to say what "deprecated" even means. `last` on OpenBSD has `-s`, but it does something _completely different_, for example.  Also, as Stephen points out in his answer, non-standard tools sometimes change rapidly and a Linux distribution may bundle one release that has a feature that others don't.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thank you so much for this update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option isn’t deprecated, it’s from the future from the perspective of your CentOS system: it was added in `util-linux` 2.24, but your distribution has an older version.

As Kusalananda says, different platforms have different implementations of `last`, supporting different features, and there isn’t even a common base (such as POSIX) for `last`. So the availability of `-s`, and its meaning, are liable to vary, especially when one considers systems which are quite different (CentOS and macOS here).

Comment: Thank you. The version of my CentOS is `7.6.1810 (Core) `.

Comment: Right, CentOS 7 has version 2.23.2.